# Get all the commands from the Run drop-down list all as text

Tags: windows, run-dialog

Is it possible to get all the command I have entered in my [Run dialog box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_command) so far as a text list?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recent Run commands can be found in the following registry branch:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU
```